# simulate effect with jquery .animate

Tags: jquery, adobe

I have an image with an effect on mouse over. 
http://www.freelancegraphicdesigner.co.uk/DPTESTS/CTA%20BUTTONS/03-ipvoice-but.html
It was done with Adobe Edge Animate, but im wondering if it's possible to simulate with simple jQuery animation or so..?

Comment: It is possible, but likely a little more like intermediate jQuery. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it is. Next question. ;)

Comment: Shew - that is quite a tough one!